# Cannot add Microsoft Tag WebService reference to MVC 4 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to add Microsoft Tag Library WebService reference to my MVC 4 application. but I can't find the web service's namespace(e.g. MyApp.Service). I took a look at [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063978/how-to-consume-a-webservice-in-mvc) and [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118931/asp-net-mvc-web-services) and [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579497/accessing-webservice-from-asp-net-mvc) and
but I didn't find my answer. can anybody tell me how to use MSTag WebService in MVC 4 app?

*It worked fine in winform apps*

Answer (score 4):

While Adding the Reference, go to the Advanced... button and uncheck Reuse types in referenced assemblies.